# Cron entry does not work

Tags: cron

I've the following entries made to take backup of php files and the apache configuration files from our web server. But i found there are no files in the backup destination folder. I would like to know if the entries have any incorrect syntax.

`# Production Events module php files from /var/events/ folder`

00 2 * * * tar cvpzf /var/backups/events/events-backup.`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar.gz /var/events/ > /var/backups/events/events-backup.log 2>&1`

`# Production Survey module php files backup from /var/survey/ folder`

00 2 * * * tar cvpzf /var/backups/survey/survey-backup.`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar.gz /var/survey/ > /var/backups/survey/survey-backup.log  2>&1

`# Apache configuration files under /etc/apache2/ directory`

00 2 * * * tar cvpzf /var/backups/apache2/apache2-backup.`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar.gz /etc/apache2/ > /var/backups/apache2/apache2-backup.log 2>&1

Comment: What happens when you run them from the command line?

Comment: It just works fine from the command line. I see both the zip and the log files created in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue today. I missed to add the user "root" just before the tar command. The following change fixed this issue.

00 2 * * * `root` tar cvpzf /var/backups/apache2/apache2-backup.date +\%Y\%m\%d.tar.gz /etc/apache2/ > /var/backups/apache2/apache2-backup.log 2>&1